# Time Query - Querying one column to be greater than another

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I'm trying to run a query which show a delay between one column date/time against another.
Ideally I'd like to be able to specify anything greater then, say, 5 hours.

I want to be able to show results where for example:

```
Select * from table
where column A is greater than column B
```

or ideally `where column A is greater than column B by 5 hours`

Comment: Date and time values can be compared by the usual operators, EG `<`... Also see `DATE_SUB()` for the "by 5 hours" part...

Answer (score 5):

use TIMESTAMPDIFF

```
  Select * from table
    where TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, start_time, end_time)>=5
```

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL, you would do:

```
where A > B
```

And then:

```
where A > B + interval 5 hour
```

I recommend getting used to this form of the comparison, rather than thinking in terms of the difference.  Although it probably makes no difference in this case, if `B` is a constant, than this can make use of an index on `A`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from table
where (column A - column B) > 5/24
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? Whats the need for all that numbers in the end?

Comment: I wanted to extract 5 hours as part of day (24h)

Answer (score 0):

The date arithmetic works in order of milliseconds.

```
select * from table where (columnA - columnB)/(1000*60*60) >= 5
```

The subtraction of date fields would yield milliseconds. So, division of milliseconds by 1000*60*60 would yield the number of hours elapsed.

Comment: Can you explain that further? Whats the need for all that numbers in the end?

Comment: @NicoHaase : milliseconds to hours conversion